# Find numeric groups from alphanumeric string following pattern +[0..9]

Tags: regex

I have a string with alphanumerical characters like this:

```
hajshajs12 +1212121 12 1AAsdsd 5665789 +987 ++789 aBcD
```

Can I extract only the numeric characters with *length >= 4* starting with `+` or without `+` using regex ?

So in the end I should have `+1212121 5665789 +987 ++789`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/7vuja5/2) regex

```
([+](?:[+]\d{2,}|\d{3,})|\d{4,})\b
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
( #Capturing group
    [+] #Match + sign
       (?:  #Non-capturing group
         [+]\d{2,} #Match another + followed by at least 2 digits
         | #Alterantion (OR)
         \d{3,} #Match at least 3 digits
       )
    | #Alterantion (OR)
    \d{4,} #Match at least 4 digits
)
\b #Word boundary. Number shouldn't be in between alphabets
```